# How can we Check if something other than a value in a list in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to know if there is a value other than a specific value in a list  in python, for example:
given a list

```
lst = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

How can I check if there is a value other than 0 in it like 1 or 2 or 3 or any number other than 0 and its position?
Example :

```
lst = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
```

The check operation should bring a `true` value saying yes list have value other than 0, that value and its position as 4.

Comment: @quamrana along with this he also wants the index of the element

Comment: @DeepakTripathi: Yes I only realised that after posting.  Deleted ...

Comment: in case of several non-zero values how should look like the output? do you need all or just the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get the positions and values of nonzero elements you can do this:

```
lst = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2]
list(filter(lambda x: x[1]!=0, enumerate(lst)))  # [(4, 1), (8, 2)]
```

Comment: instead of `list(` use `next(` to get first

Answer (score 1):

You can use `enumerate` to get values plus their index in the list.

```
lst = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
baddies = [i for i,val in enumerate(lst)]
has_baddies = bool(baddies)
```

To short-circuit on the first bad apple a for loop would be a good option

```
for baddie, val in enumerate(lst):
    if has_baddies := val != 0:
        break
else:
    baddie = None
```

Comment: @DeepakTripathi - Why is that bad? I think its a fair reading of your question. If you only wanted the first, or if there was at most one to find, wouldn't you have mentioned that?

Comment: sorry my bad deleting my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same output as @SergFSM, this is another tricky option using `collections`:

```
lst = [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2]
print([f"({lst.index(f)}, {f})" for f in dict(collections.Counter(lst)) if f != 0])
```

['(4, 1)', '(8, 2)']

Comment: `dict` is redundant since `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`. The code is bugged for repeated numbers, i.e. `lst  = [0, 2, 3, 2]`. A dictionary like approach is a bad idea since you loose reference of repeated values (you keep track of the frequency but is not relevant)

Comment: ...and `list.index` returns the 1st occurrence in the list

Answer (score 0):

Use `itertools.compress` from the standard library. Take advantage that `0` is cast to `False`:

```
from itertools import compress

lst = [0,0,0,0,1,0,99, 0,0]

res = list(compress(enumerate(lst), lst))

if res:
    print(*res)
else:
    print('Only 0s.')
```