# How to match two lists in Python with some condition using zip?

Tags: python, list

I want to zip two lists. For example:

```py
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
b = [0, 2, 1, 4]
```

And I have to left in the list only objects that don't match with `0`.
So for lists `a` and `b` I have to get list `c`:

```py
c = ['b', 'c', 'd']
```

How can I do this with python? I tried using loop, but it works too long. Maybe I have to use `zip()` method, but I don't know exactly how to use it :(

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663807/how-do-i-iterate-through-two-lists-in-parallel

Comment: [Similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74157557/how-can-we-check-if-something-other-than-a-value-in-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You could combine zip with list comprehension as follows:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
b = [0, 2, 1, 4]

c = [x for (x,y) in list(zip(a,b)) if y != 0]
```

outputs: `['b', 'c', 'd']`

Comment: Thank you!
But what do I have to do if I have a lot of lists like list b and I have to match all these lists with list like a?

Comment: What you must do is to ask a new question on this site explaining how these `b` lists work, giving a few examples, plus the code you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a perfect job for `compress` from `itertools`

```
from itertools import compress

a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
b = [0, 2, 1, 4]

print(*compress(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
c = [x for x, y in zip(a, b) if y != 0]
```

This will work fine when both lists have the same length. If list `a` was longer and you'd want the extra elements out too, you could use this version:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

c = [x for x, y in zip_longest(a, b) if y != 0 and x is not None]
```